# USB HDD mounted to a folder in the home drive is not shown as available space on Windows using SMB

Tags: mount, samba

I have a 2TB drive on my machine mounted as /home/Louis/Downloads and that works fine:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  1,8T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0  1,8T  0 part /home/Louis/Downloads 
mmcblk0     179:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  100M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  100G  0 part /
```

I have a SMB config sharing `/home/Louis/` over the network and I can access it from Windows just fine, the problem is that the reported size in Windows is just 100GB (The size of my `/home` partition) and not 2,1 TB of the whole `/home` folder.

Here's the `smb.conf`:

```
[Home]
 comment = Home Folder
 read only = no
 locking = no
 path = "/home/Louis"
 guest ok = no
 browsable = yes
 valid users = pine
 create mode = 0644
 directory mode = 0755
 create mask = 0644
 force create mask = 0644
 directory mask = 0755
 force group = pine
 force user = pine
 public = no
 writeable = yes
```

If I directly mount `/home/Louis/Downloads` in Windows, I get access to the whole 2TB, but I can't get to the rest of my /home/Louis stuff without using 2 letters in Windows, and I'd like to use just 1.

Comment: I don't know the easiest way to say it, but that is not how a Samba mount works.  Just linking or mounting a drive within the folder does not automatically make more size available to the drive.  If that were the case then your 100GB / mount would then be 1.9T in size.  Windows following through is going to see the exact same thing.  Are you having a problem accessing the `/home/Louis/Downloads` folder from the first drive mount?

Comment: I can mount `/home/Louis/Downloads` just fine and I see all the available space as expected. I just wanted to know if it would be possible to see the drive mounted to `Downloads` and its space through the parent folder `/home/Louis`.